# BTS flat file schema generate with unbounded max records inside

Tags: biztalk, flat-file

I have a problem with generate/create schema for input document as flatfile in Visual studio with BTS Dev tools.

please look at the example:

[image]

**[User Story]**

as you can see schema is a ***CSV formated flat file***.

Marked on **green** is a customer lvl (segment) and can exist couple times in input file (unbounded). Inside of this **customer segment** we will find **CUST** and **CUST_INF** records, thous records can exist in **first** case **min : 1**, **max: 1** and in **second** case **min: 0**, **max: 1**.

Marked on red is a invoice lvl (segment) and can exist couple times in input file  (unbounded). Inside of this segment we will find INV (min: 1, max: 1) and INV_INFO (min: 0, max: 1) and INV_LIN (min: 1 max: unbounded).

**[QUESTION]**

How to create **valid** schema for this case ?

```
INFO;field_1;field_2;field_3;
CUST;field_1;field_2;field_3;
CUST_INF;field_1;field_2;field_3;
CUST;field_1;field_2;field_3;
CUST_INF;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV_INF;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV_LIN;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV_LIN;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV_LIN;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV_INF;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV_LIN;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV_LIN;field_1;field_2;field_3;
```

[UPDATE 15-11-2016]

```
INFO;field_1;field_2;field_3;
CUST;field_1;field_2;field_3;
CUST_INF;field_1;field_2;field_3;
CUST;field_1;field_2;field_3;
CUST_INF;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV_INF;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV_LIN;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV_LIN;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV_LIN;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV;field_1;field_2;field_3; <-- validation stop 

INV_LIN;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV_LIN;field_1;field_2;field_3;
```

I've removed **LIN_INF** record (I mean empty line too) from input doc in **second INV segment** (this record is optional), at this moment **validation** will **stop** at the end of line of second segment "INV;field_1;field_2;field_3;".

[UPDATE 16.11.2016]

> SCHEMA

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Test.FlatFileSchema1" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Test.FlatFileSchema1" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" codepage="65001" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" root_reference="Root" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0xD 0xA" child_order="infix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element name="INFO">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo tag_name="INFO;" structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter=";" child_order="postfix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="Root_Child1_Child1" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Root_Child1_Child2" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="Root_Child1_Child3" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <groupInfo sequence_number="2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="CUST">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                <b:recordInfo tag_name="CUST;" structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter=";" child_order="postfix" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="1" />
              </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:element name="Root_Child2_Child1" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Root_Child2_Child2" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Root_Child2_Child3" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CUST_INF">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                <b:recordInfo tag_name="CUST_INF;" structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter=";" child_order="postfix" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="2" />
              </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:element name="Root_Child3_Child1" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Root_Child3_Child2" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Root_Child3_Child3" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <groupInfo sequence_number="3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:element minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" name="INV">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                <b:recordInfo tag_name="INV;" structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter=";" child_order="postfix" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="1" />
              </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:element name="Root_Child6_Child1" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Root_Child6_Child2" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Root_Child6_Child3" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="INV_INF">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                <b:recordInfo tag_name="INV_INF;" structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter=";" child_order="postfix" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="2" />
              </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:element name="Root_Child7_Child1" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Root_Child7_Child2" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Root_Child7_Child3" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" name="INV_LIN">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                <b:recordInfo tag_name="INV_LIN;" structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter=";" child_order="postfix" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="3" />
              </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:element name="Root_Child8_Child1" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Root_Child8_Child2" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="Root_Child8_Child3" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

> EXAMPLE DATA

```
INFO;field_1;field_2;field_3;
CUST;field_1;field_2;field_3;
CUST_INF;field_1;field_2;field_3;
CUST;field_1;field_2;field_3;
CUST_INF;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV_INF;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV_LIN;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV_LIN;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV_LIN;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV_LIN;field_1;field_2;field_3;
INV_LIN;field_1;field_2;field_3;
```

> ERRORS

```
Error   1   Unexpected data found while looking for:
'INV_INF;'
'INV;'
The current definition being parsed is Root. The stream offset where the error occured is 359. The line number where the error occured is 12. The column where the error occured is 0.  C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\test.txt 1   1
```

Comment: Can you please give a sample in text (rather than graphics) that contains multiple customers, and invoices so we can see how they occur multiple times?

Comment: Does your last line have a CR LF after the last line?  If so you need to change your root node from Child Order Infix to Postfix.

Comment: @Dijkgraaf yea, you have right, I had Infix, thx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use the Flat File Wizard.  Add, New Item, Flat File Schema Wizard, give the schema a name and click Add. Click next
2. Select the Instance File (example message) and click Next
3. On the record being defined: /Root just leave things as they are and click Next.
4. Format, leave as By delimiter symbol and click Next
5. Child delimiter: {CR}{LF}  is correct so click Next.
6. Change the Element Name and the Element Type to Record, Repeating Record or Ignore (Note: I'm Ignoring all but the first instance of each type, see below, and I've marked CUST_INF as a repeating one so I can ignore the following lines). click Next.

[image]

Then it wants you to define each record.  You will have to repeat the following steps for each record

7. Click Next, Next, Next, set Child delimiter to ;
8. Click Record has a tag identifier and enter the tag for that record e.g. INFO; click Next  (Note: I'm including the ; in the tag, otherwise it treats it as prefix delimited rather than a postfix delimited record and you end up with an empty field at the end of each record).
9. Set the Element Name and types, click Next

Repeat above steps until you have done all the records and click Finish.

Now you will have a base schema that will look like below.  However that will not validate yet as we have to define some of the repeating groups following the steps below.

[image]

10. Right click the Root node and Add a Sequence Group, set the Max Occurs to unbounded by entering a *
11. Cut and past the CUST & CUST_INF nodes into the sequence node
12. Update the CUST_INF to have a Min Occurs 0 and Max Occurs 1 (the 1 is optional as the default is 1)
13. Right click the Root node and Add a Sequence Group, set the Max Occurs to unbounded by entering a *
14. Cut and past the INV, INV_INF & INV_LIN into the second sequence group
15. Set the INV_INF to Min Occurs 0 and Max Occurs 1 (the 1 is optional as the default is 1)

Your schema should now look like this and be able to parse your flat file.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<xs:schema xmlns="http://Scratch.FlatFileSchema40595371w" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://Scratch.FlatFileSchema40595371w" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
    <xs:appinfo>
      <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" />
      <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" codepage="65001" default_pad_char=" " pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" root_reference="Root" />
    </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:annotation>
      <xs:appinfo>
        <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0xD 0xA" child_order="postfix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
      </xs:appinfo>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:annotation>
          <xs:appinfo>
            <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
          </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
        <xs:element name="INFO">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <b:recordInfo tag_name="INFO;" structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter=";" child_order="postfix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:annotation>
                <xs:appinfo>
                  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                </xs:appinfo>
              </xs:annotation>
              <xs:element name="INFO_Child1" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="INFO_Child2" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
              <xs:element name="INFO_Child3" type="xs:string">
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
        <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <groupInfo sequence_number="2" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:element name="CUST">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                <b:recordInfo tag_name="CUST;" structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter=";" child_order="postfix" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="1" />
              </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:element name="CUST_Child1" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="CUST_Child2" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="CUST_Child3" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="CUST_INF">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                <b:recordInfo tag_name="CUST_INF;" structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter=";" child_order="postfix" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="2" />
              </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:element name="CUST_INF_Child1" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="CUST_INF_Child2" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="CUST_INF_Child3" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
              <groupInfo sequence_number="3" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
            </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
          <xs:element name="INV">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                <b:recordInfo tag_name="INV;" structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter=";" child_order="postfix" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="1" />
              </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:element name="INV_Child1" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="INV_Child2" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="INV_Child3" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element minOccurs="0" name="INV_INF">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                <b:recordInfo tag_name="INV_INF;" structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter=";" child_order="postfix" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="2" />
              </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:element name="INV_INF_Child1" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="INV_INF_Child2" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="INV_INF_Child3" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="INV_LIN">
            <xs:annotation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                <b:recordInfo tag_name="INV_LIN;" structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter=";" child_order="postfix" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" sequence_number="3" />
              </xs:appinfo>
            </xs:annotation>
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:annotation>
                  <xs:appinfo>
                    <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" />
                  </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
                <xs:element name="INV_LIN_Child1" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="INV_LIN_Child2" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="INV_LIN_Child3" type="xs:string">
                  <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                      <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" />
                    </xs:appinfo>
                  </xs:annotation>
                </xs:element>
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

[UPDATE 15-11-2016]

If you have a blank like like that, just add a Choice Node put the INV_INF below it and add another record with no Tag and one field below it so it looks like below.  If CUST_INF can also be replaced by a blank, then do the same for that node.

[image]

Comment: I have one question, when document is validate on output I've got XML output doc, basically its OK, but validating stopped (positive) on record that is not in input doc, example: INV_INFO is optional and this record net exist in this place in input doc, validating will stop before this record on record above, what is the reason ? How to fix it ?

Comment: @Nerus I'm not quite sure what you are asking. Can you post a new question with a sample document, the schema you are using and what the output is vs what you expect?

Comment: @Nerus Is there actually a blank/empty line between INV & INV_LIN?  Then if so I've added an update to the answer

Comment: no, only in example for showing with line I removed

Comment: @Nerus It works for me, are you sure you set the Min Occurs (not the Group Min Occurs) to zero on the INV_INF record?

Comment: Please look at [UPDATE 16.11.2016]